# ¿Cómo puedo probar un servicio en SoapUI que reciba como parámetro un archivo (MultipartFile)?

Tags: java, spring, soapui

¿Cómo puedo probar en SoapUI este servicio?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cargarArchivo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public void cargarDatos(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    //
}
```

He estado buscando por Internet y por la misma aplicación la forma de adicionar el parámetro File pero no lo logro encontrar la opción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estos son los pasos a seguir para enviar un archivo a un servicio web con el SoapUI v.5.2.1:

1. Seleccionar POST como método de la petición.
2. Escoger multipart/form-data como Media Type.
3. Clic en la pestaña Attachments.
4. Clic en el símbolo + verde y seleccionar el archivo.
5. Este paso es opcional. Marcar si es necesario el check Post QueryString.

Si se necesita indicar el id con el que se enviará el archivo, se puede indicar en la pestaña "Attachments" en la columna "ContentId".

[image: Captura de pantalla SoapUI cómo enviar un archivo a servicio web]

Comment: Gracias

¿Donde puedo indicar que se esta enviando el parámetro "file"?.
Estoy obteniendo este error:

{
   "timestamp": 1496352057726,
   "status": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
   "message": "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present",
   "path": "/proyecto-cargue/archivos/cargarArchivo"
}

Comment: Creo que es en la pestaña de "Attachments" en la columna "ContentId" cambia el valor a "file".

Comment: Si era en la columna "ContentId", ya obtuve la respuesta esperada.
Gracias kerten.

Comment: De nada. Si la respuesta te ha sido útil, recuerda marcarla como correcta en el check verde.